# $(this) and find doesn't work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a children of the div form-group, more specifically I'm trying to print out the value of the input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>text</label>
    <input name="text" type="text" class="form-control" value="123456" />
    <script>
        alert($(this).find("input").val());
    </script>
</div>
```

why this code doesn't work? I get `undefined`. I should get `123456`

Comment: you are not using `$(this)` properly. Try `$('input.form-control').val()` - or, simply `$('input').val()`

Comment: As `this` is the `window` so `$(this.document)` or `$(document)` or just `$('input')` will work the same:) But why are you using `this` here?

Comment: I have many forms and inputs so since the javascript code is inside each div (like in the example above) I wanted to reference each div by using jquery this but apparently this doesn't point to the enclosing div, right?

Comment: $("input").val() will display the value of the first input in my document which is not this one. I want to reference this input div without id nor name

Comment: You seem to be under the misconception that your script is within the scope of your HTML. It doesn't work like that at all, the location of the `<script>` tag is completely irrelevant and `this` in your script block refers to the `window` object.

Comment: @Andy, thank you, now it's clear. So there's no way to reference a div without id nor name?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Or with a class: `$('.form-control')` returns all form controls, `$('.form-control').eq(0)` returns the first form control.

Comment: cool. thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(this) is pointing to parent instruction. For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '.element', function(){
    $(this).find('input').val();
})
```

In this case $(this) target is ".element". In your example you are pointing to nothing so you can't get any value.

Comment: You can try something like this:

alert($('.form-group').find('input[name="text"]').val());

input[name="text"] - that means you are looking for input with attribute name = text
But this is not save method in case when you have many inputs with the same name attr in ".form-group" div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var inputElement = $(document.currentScript).parent().find('input');
alert(inputElement.val());
```